# Error creating bean with name 'PesquisaController' defined in file [target/classes/br/com/controller/PesquisaController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency

Tags: spring, kotlin

I dont now what I am doing wrong with this project. I am just trying to write a Controller+Service+Repository project.

But I cant run my app because of this error:

`Error creating bean with name 'pesquisaController' defined in file [target/classes/br/com/controller/PesquisaController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pesquisaService'`

my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>br.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>back</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>back</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <kotlin.code.style>official</kotlin.code.style>
        <kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>1.8</kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>
        <kotlin.version>1.6.0</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>all-open</plugin>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                        <plugin>no-arg</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

my controller:

```
package br.com.controller

import br.com.service.PesquisaService
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/pesquisas")
class PesquisaController(

    @Autowired
    private val pesquisaService: PesquisaService
) {

    @GetMapping("/teste")
    fun teste(): Long{
        return pesquisaService.listarPesquisas()
    }
}
```

entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pesquisa")
class Pesquisa {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private val id: Long? = null

    @NotNull
    private val qtdMoradores: String? = null
```

I tried put this in my Application class but didn't work

```
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = ["br.com"],
    basePackageClasses = [br.com.controller.PesquisaController::class])
```

is there other option to make this work? i almost giving up hahahahhahaha

Answer (score 0):

I asked my friend and he resolved the problem. I'll put the answer here just in case someone needed:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```